# HTML.ActionLink() generating incorrect URLs

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, url-routing

I'm having difficulty getting HTML.ActionLink() create correct links.

When I am at 
http://localhost:49242/

My options are:

- http://localhost:49242/en-us/PinnedSites ,
- http://localhost:49242/en-us/addons ,
- http://localhost:49242/en-us/trackingprotectionlists

But when I navigate to http://localhost:49242/en-us/PinnedSites my options are:

- http://localhost:49242/en-us/PinnedSites/PinnedSites ,
- http://localhost:49242/en-us/PinnedSites/addons ,
- http://localhost:49242/en-us/PinnedSites/trackingprotectionlists

All of these urls fail, of course.

Here's my html:

#### .cshtml (Html / razor)

```
<li id="nav_pinning">
    @Html.ActionLink( "pinned sites", "index", "PinnedSites")</li>
<li id="nav_addons">
    @Html.ActionLink("add-ons", "index", "addons")</li>
<li id="nav_control">
    @Html.ActionLink("tracking protection lists", 
                    "index", 
                    "trackingprotectionlists",
                    null,
                    null)</li>
```

#### Global.asax.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{culture}/{controller}/{action}", 
            new { culture = "en-us", 
                controller = "Home", 
                action = "Index", 
            }
        );
    }
```

Where is my problem?  Is it possible that /PinnedSites/ is not actually going to the PinnedSitesController?

(And I will be actively watching this, please comment if you want me to try things or provide more code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a HomeController as part of your project? If so you should register the default controller along the lines of:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
         "Default", // Route name
         "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

However, that aside have you tried simply making the Route directly to your PinnedSites controller?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{culture}/{controller}/{action}", 
            new { culture = "en-us", 
                controller = "PinnedSites", 
                action = "Index", 
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer, but got me thinking in the right direction to figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: hi @Civilian I have the same problem. What's your solution? cheers

Comment: Hey @Franva sorry, this was 3 years ago, so I don't remember and I don't have the code anymore. But I think it was a mistake in how I was registering routes, the Razor code was correct.

Comment: hi @Civilian no worris, I have figured it out. I used the wrong parameter :)